# Vim: Motion for more than one surrounding parantheses

Tags: vim, comments, vim-plugin

I'm currently learning vim. I use the package [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) which enables the `gc` operation.

I have the following function:

```
function useToggleContext() {
//         if (!context) {
//           throw new Error(
//             "Toggle compound components must be rendered within the Toggle component."
//           );
//         }
}
```

I want to comment in the code which is currently commented out.

When I'm on line 2 (the line with the `if`) I can do `gci}` to comment in the code. But what if I'm on line 4 (the line with the string)?

What is the motion to select the surrounding curly brackets for two levels (the `if`'s surrounding brackets and the `function`'s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know vim-commentary, but from Vim logic it should be `gc2i}`.

The `i}` is a text-object "inner Block". If it is prefixed with a count, it selects count Blocks. See `:help text-object`.

You can use `2i}` with other actions like `d`. If you are on line 4 and hit `d2i}` it will delete the entire content of the function and and you get

```
function useToggleContext() {
}
```

Comment: When I try `gc2i}`, I only get ```            throw new Error(
              "Toggle compound components must be rendered within the Toggle component."
            );
          }``` commented in, so the first line is missing.

Comment: I downloaded vim-commentary and did a short test. For me it works as I said. I extended the answer, to add more background.

Comment: Weird. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using [Vim for VSCode](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim)? I'll just accept your answer and I'm going to figure out what is going wrong. Thank you!